# Quel serait le nom francisé des planètes/dieux romains?

Tags: latin

Parmi les planètes du système solaire, seules deux ont reçu un nom latin sans adaptation à la langue française: Venus et Uranus.

Pour le second, Urane a été utilisé, comme cité ci-dessous (et suit la logique des autres noms que sont Saturne, Neptune, …) mais pour Vénus je ne trouve rien.

J'imagine que ce serait Vénée ou Véne mais j'aimerais une source sur la francisation du nom de la déesse.

**Source (dieu).** *Dictionnaire universel françois et latin*, Volume 5 page 1331.

> Saturne étoit fils d'Urane. Il fut fait premier Roi des Titans.

**Source (planète).** *L'influence des astres* (1946) d'Ad. Ferrière

> Le trigone Urane-Neptune devait durer presque toute la guerre.

Comment: Urane n'a pas jamais été utilisé pour désigner Uranus (que ce soit le Dieu ou la Planète). L'urane est un corps chimique ( désigné il me semble de nos jours sous le nom d'oxyde d'uranium, je ne suis pas calé en chimie).  « 1790  empr. à l'allemand *Uran*, nom donné par [Klaproth](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heinrich_Klaproth), en hommage à [Herschel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Herschel) qui avait découvert la planète Uranus en 1781. ». Le prénom Vénus existant en français, je ne comprends pas bien ta question. Proposer des idées de francisation ?

Comment: @None "Urane n'a pas jamais été utilisé pour désigner Uranus" Ce n'est pas parce que tu n'as pas réussi à trouver un tel usage qu'il n'existe pas. J'ai ajouté une source en fin de question.

Comment: Je ne l'avais pas trouvé car je ne l'avais pas cherché, à celui qui pose la question de jusitifer ce qu'il dit. Tu ne donnes qu'une seule occurrence et de plus ce même ouvrage n'a pas d'entrée à Urane (ni même Uranus, la planète n'était pas encore découverte au début du 18e siècle mais le Dieu était connu). As-tu des articles de dictionnaires ou encyclopédies (si possible plus récents) permettant de parler d'« usage », une seule occurrence ne le permettant pas. Toutes celles que je viens de consulter ignore urane pour la planète ou le dieu, ils ne connaissent qu’Uranus.

Comment: Pour en revenir à Vénus il existe bien une pseudo « francisation » dans **vendre** de vendredi (« le jour de Vénus ») mais je pense pas que ce soit le genre de chose que tu cherches. Je n'ai pas encore bien compris la question.

Comment: @None Il suffit d'un seul exemple pour prouver que "Urane n'a pas jamais été utilisé" est faux. J'ai cependant ajouté une source pour le nom de la planète

Comment: @None Oui c'est le genre de chose que je cherche. Une francisation pour le mot lui-même (plutôt qu'en tant que composé) serait encore mieux mais c'est un début. Merci pour ce commentaire.

Comment: Tu vas pas reprendre les fautes de frappe des commentaires à chaque fois. On ne peut pas modifier les commentaires. « Urane n'a pas été utilisé pour...  ». Non, je suis désolé mais un seul exemple ne suffit pas à dire qu'« un tel usage » existe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132701/discussion-between-laravel-and-none).

Comment: La terminaison en -ée de mots comme musée, diarrhée, Énée ou Thésée est normalement utilisée pour des paroxytones dont la voyelle tonique est immédiatement suivie par une autre voyelle (Muséum, diarrhœ́a, Aenéas, Theséus). Ce n'est pas du tout le cas de Vénus, donc la forme "Vénée" proposée est très peu probable.

Comment: Je suspecte que les savants de la Renaissance auraient préféré emprunter l'accusatif Veneram en Vénère (cf l'adjectif vénérien) plutôt que le nominatif Venus, mais c'est très difficile à rechercher à cause des formes du verbe vénérer.

Comment: Quand à la forme héritée en droite ligne du latin, ça serait normalement Viendre (vénerem > */'viɛnrə/ > viendre). Vendredi est similaire mais atone donc le /ɛ/ initial ne s'est pas diphtongué

Comment: @Eauquidort merci beaucoup vous avez parfaitement compris la question. Je fais des recherches à la lumière de vos explications

Comment: @Eauquidort Avez-vous une référence pour ces questions? Cela m'intéresse beaucoup